# New Google Analytics event tracking wont work on mailto

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, dom-events, event-tracking

I'm using the latest Google Analytics code:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){  
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;
    i[r]=i[r]||function(){ (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();
         a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;
         a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m) })
      (window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'XXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXX');   
      ga('send', 'pageview');
```

I've got event tracking to work on a download link using the following:

```
<a href="#" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Download', 'PDF', 'FILE NAME');">
```

However, it's not working on a mailto link - when I look in the console it says the request has been cancelled. This is what I'm using:

```
<a href="mailto:email@address.com" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Contact', 'Email', 'Name here');">
```

When I remove the "mailto" it will then track.

Am I setting it up wrong?

EDIT: It appears if I put a `target="_blank"` it will work - however it then opens up another window which isn't ideal.

Second Edit: It appears it's something to do with Chrome - I tested it in Firefox and IE and it worked when I did that - anyone else experienced this?

Comment: have you tried using `onmousedown` instead of `onclick`?

Comment: Hi Eduardo - I tried onmousedown and it worked - thank you! This seems like the best solution to me as you don't need the extra markup!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a relevant thread here: [Google Analytics Event Tracking not firing for multiple accounts on Chrome ONLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226302/google-analytics-event-tracking-not-firing-for-multiple-accounts-on-chrome-only)

So in the end I got it working with chrome - this is how it looks now for those interested:

```
<a onclick="setTimeout(function(){ga('send', 'event', 'Email', 'Person Name');}, 1500);" href="mailto:email@address.com" >
```

A timeout function had to be added.

As Eduardo pointed out above another option that worked was having a mousedown function:

```
<a onmousedown="ga('send', 'event', 'Email', 'Person Name');" href="mailto:email@address.com" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Universal Analytics has built-in functionality for delaying sends called [hitCallback](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback).

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Contact', 'Email', 'Name here', {
  'hitCallback': function() {
    document.location.href = this.href
  }
});
```

Haven't tested it, but should be pretty close to working. Google-around for other ideas.