# Google Analytics Event Tracking Multiple Events on the Same Page

Tags: google-analytics

I am attempting to log an event via Google Analytics when a user clicks certain links on our site's home page. I want to log when the user clicks the link for our telephone number, and also when they click the link for our email address.

I can get the first event to be logged, but any subsequent events are not being logged. I do not see any JavaScript errors, however in the Network tab of Chrome's Dev Tools window, I see that the Status of these network events is "(canceled)"

Can anyone point me to a working example of multiple events working on a single page? Does Google Analytics support multiple events on a single page?

Per request, I have added an example of the code I am using:

The links with events attached (again, the first click/event is working, any subsequent clicks/events are not)

```
<p class="lead">Call Now: <a href="tel:5555555555" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Default', 'Click', 'PhoneTop');" style="color: #ddd;" >555-555-5555</a></p>
<p class="lead">Email: <a href="mailto:contact@example.com" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Default', 'Click', 'EmailTop');" style="color: #ddd;">contact@example.com</a></p>
```

And the Google Analytics code:

```
<script>
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
ga('create', 'UA-55555555-1', 'example.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Comment: could you post some code?  Yes you can have multiple events.

Comment: @DaImTo, absolutely, in this case, what code would you like to see?

Comment: The links, the JS event tracking code you are using.  There is no limit to the number of events that you can send in one page, so if the event isn't being tracked there is probably something wrong with your code.

Comment: @DaImTo, I've added the code you requested. Again, the first event is being logged successfully, any subsequent events are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with Chrome and tracking mailto and tel links (more here: [New Google Analytics event tracking wont work on mailto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834417/new-google-analytics-event-tracking-wont-work-on-mailto))

I resolved this issue by adding a setTimeout() to the onclick()

```
<p class="lead">Call Now: <a href="tel:5555555555" onclick="setTimeout(function () { ga('send', 'event', 'Default', 'Click', 'PhoneTop'); }, 500);" style="color: #ddd;" >555-555-5555</a></p>
<p class="lead">Email: <a href="mailto:contact@example.com" onclick="setTimeout(function () { ga('send', 'event', 'Default', 'Click', 'EmailTop'); }, 500);" style="color: #ddd;">contact@example.com</a></p>
```